# Dialog Box example in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to display a dialog box on a button click. Here is my code, but it is not working.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
```

Comment: What is the problem/error-message? "Not working" is not a problem-description ;)

Comment: Where this code is placed? In onCreate()? Then it is wrong. Dialog showing should be called when activity has been shown, so put this code in some button onClickListener.

Comment: if you are using alert dialog then it is not need to dismiss for alert dialog. when you will click on button of alert dialog it will be automatically dismiss..

Comment: Problem solved. I placed the code in onCreate() method. I corrected it and placed it in a button onClick() method, its working perfectly. Thanks Mr.  Vladimir Ivanov.

Comment: I can use this very code to ask my query..what does this positiveButton, negative and neutral button?

Comment: Check this link is usefull to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965122/android-how-to-align-message-in-alertdialog/22558128#22558128

Answer (score 7):

try this,

instead of passing getApplicationContext() pass this;

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post however I have made a class that I think it can help to keep the code clean

https://github.com/houmanka/DialogMaker

You dont need to worry about the OnClickListener all have been taking care of. Just override the methods and you are done. Also I put the support for Standard and Neutral too.

Cheers

Hope it helps someone.
H.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as OP is using.