# Right justify text in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, justify

Is it possible to right-justify the text in an AlertDialog's title and message?

I am showing Hebrew messages but they are showing up left justified.

Comment: I used this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under/23278774#23278774

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can see from the code of [`AlertDialog`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:android/app/AlertDialog.java) and [`AlertController`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:android/app/AlertDialog.java) you can't access the `TextView`s responsible for message and title.

You can use reflection to reach `mAlert` field in AlertDialog instance, and then again use reflection to access `mMessage` and `mTitle` fields of `mAlert`. Though I wouldn't recommend this approach as it relies on internals (which might change in future).

---

As another (and probably much better) solution, you can apply custom theme via `AlertDialog` constructor. This would allow you to right-justify all `TextView`s in that dialog.

```
     protected AlertDialog (Context context, int theme)
```

This should be easier and more robust approach.

---

Here is step by step instructions:

**Step 1.** Create `res/values/styles.xml` file. Here its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="RightJustifyTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RightJustifyDialogWindowTitle" parent="@android:style/DialogWindowTitle" >
         <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RightJustifyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RightJustifyTextView</item>       
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/RightJustifyDialogWindowTitle</item>       
    </style>    

</resources>
```

**Step 2.** Create `RightJustifyAlertDialog.java` file. Here its content:

```
public class RightJustifyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog
{
    public RightJustifyAlertDialog(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx,  R.style.RightJustifyTheme);
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** Use `RightJustifyAlertDialog` dialog:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new RightJustifyAlertDialog(this);
dialog.setButton("button", new OnClickListener()
{           
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
    {

    }
});
dialog.setTitle("Some Title");
dialog.setMessage("Some message");

dialog.show();
```

**Step 4.** Check the results:

[image]

Comment: Do I have to define all the theme or is there a base line I can build on? I haven't used themes before.

Comment: You can inherit the default theme and just add your changes. For example, in your `styles.xml` you could create a new theme called `CustomTheme` and start it like this:`<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">`. Then you would only have to add the items you want changed.

Comment: I tried doing mydialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme) but it claims that the constructor doesn't exists.

Comment: No, unfortunatelly 'AlertDialog.Builder(Context, int  theme)` was introduced only in API Level 11. You should use `AlertDialog(Context, int theme)` instead, and configure the dialog manually.

Comment: Is there any example out there of configuring manually? Also, what option should I be setting in the theme in order to make the fields right justified? Should I build my own XML file and use it as the layout?

Comment: I am still seriously stuck here. Not sure how to get to the text and title fields (in order to right-justify them) even if I define a custom AlertDialog.

Comment: I've added detailed step-by-step instructions to the question. Try it out.

Comment: Thx! You are awesome! Works wonderful. Just one small thing. It fills the whole screen instead of just being a pop-up in the middle.

Comment: It shouldn't. At least in my project it was centered. Try doing all the steps above in new clean project.

Comment: Same happens in a clean project

Comment: I cann't reproduce this in my environment. Could you maybe download you project somewhere and post link here?

Comment: Weird thing is that it works OK on Eclipse in the AVD emulator. However, as soon I as install it on my device (Xperia X10a) it goes weird.

Comment: It might be because of different API Levels. What is your Xperia Android SDK version?

Comment: My phone says Firmware: 2.1-update1 which is what I am using in the emulator. Also, it is only this that has the problems. A "normal" AlterDialog" is ok.

Comment: I'm really confused. The last thing you can try is changing your `default.properties` file: replace target value with `target=android-9`.

Comment: I am assuming u mean android-7 since that is equivalent to 2.1-update1

Comment: Yes, change it to android-9. See if it helps. I see different behaviors of dialog with different values.

Comment: Nope - no change. Super-weird.

Comment: Still stuck here if anyone can help.

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve the issue you had. Make screenshots with new theme applied and create new question with all the steps you did and other details you described here is comments. Maybe somebody else will be able to help you.

Comment: Ok - thanks. I'll also upload the mini-project I created and give a link to it.

Comment: this is not working on the AppCompat them and dialog

Comment: This no longer works, aapt gives an error: @android:style/DialogWindowTitle is private, and also resource android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert is private.

Answer (score 31):

This is an old question, but there is a very simple solution. Assuming you are using `MinSdk 17`, you can add this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
</style>
```

And in the `AlertDialog.Builder` you just need to specify this `AlertDialogCustom` in the constructor:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom)
                    .setTitle("Your title?")
                    .show();
```

Comment: I pretty much like your solution and it changes everything including buttons, but title and message text are not showing, any tips?

Comment: use `parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"` for setting your theme in custom alert dialog.

Answer (score 17):

If you want a quick and easy way to do this, I would just create and modify the default alert using AlertDialog.Builder.  You can even create a convenience method and class like so:

```
/** Class to simplify display of alerts. */
public class MyAlert {

    public static void alert(Context context, String title, String message, OnClickListener listener)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("My Title");
        builder.setMessage("My message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", listener);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

        // Must call show() prior to fetching views
        TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        TextView titleView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));
        if (titleView != null) {
            titleView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
       }
    }
}
```

Of course you could also change the gravity to CENTER for center alignment instead of right or the default left.

Comment: Works great, but I got another problem. Title & text are aligned fine, but buttons aren't. How to get buttons by id?

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this for an hour (the solutions above didn't work for me), I managed to align the AlertDialog's title and message to the right, without overriding any styles, simply changing the gravity and layout params.

In DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Set title and message
    try {
        alignDialogRTL(getDialog(), this);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

The actual function:

```
public static void alignDialogRTL(Dialog dialog, Context context) {
    // Get message text view
    TextView message = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

    // Defy gravity
    message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    // Get title text view
    TextView title = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));

    // Defy gravity (again)
    title.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    // Get title's parent layout
    LinearLayout parent = ((LinearLayout)Title.getParent());

    // Get layout params
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams originalParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)parent.getLayoutParams();

    // Set width to WRAP_CONTENT
    originalParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    // Defy gravity (last time)
    originalParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT |  Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    // Set updated layout params
    parent.setLayoutParams(originalParams);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The kotlinish way :

```
val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()

alertDialog.setOnShowListener {

   alertDialog.window?.decorView?.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
                               }

alertDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to create a style tag in res/values/styles and write :

```
<style name="alertDialog LayoutDirection">
<item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
```

and then add this after alert dialog initializing in your activity :

```
alertDialog.setView(R.style.alertDialog);
```

for example :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("حذف بشه؟")
                .setCancelable(true);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("آره", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("نه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.setView(R.style.alertDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting layout direction of alert dialog to RTL you can use OnShowListener method.
after setting title , message , ....  use this method.

```
dialog = alertdialogbuilder.create();

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dlg) {
                dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(20); // set text size of positive button
                dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED); set text color of positive button

                dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL); // set title and message direction to RTL
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```