# how set to the CENTER title in AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom dialog on Android: How can I center its title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025605/custom-dialog-on-android-how-can-i-center-its-title)

I have  code:

```
     return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

            .setTitle("Warning!")
            .setMessage("message!")
            .setPositiveButton("yes ",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
```

etc...
   how             .setTitle("Warning!") set to the CENTER?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027385/2106820

Comment: This one works better https://stackoverflow.com/a/43467974/3798399

Answer (score 3):

You cannot center the title in the default alert dialog.

You will need to create a custom dialog in order to center the title.

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025605/custom-dialog-on-android-how-can-i-center-its-title) describe how it can be done.