# Android - Menu Items don't show up in Arabic

Tags: android, eclipse, menuitem, arabic

I am making an Android app, and want to display a Menu of two items (Home Page , Logout).
My problem exactly is the Menu items don't show up at all when i switch my phone's language to Arabic.

When i set my phone to the English language, the Menu item shows up and all work superfine. unless when i switch the phone's language to Arabic, every text showing up in Arabic except the Menu. No Menu at all..!! please any help??

Here is the java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.home_page:

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Home Page")
        .setMessage("You Are In The Home Page Now")
        .setNeutralButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //Do Nothing
            }
        }).show();


        break;

    case R.id.logout:

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Attention!!")
        .setMessage("Do You Really Want To Logout?")
        .setNeutralButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //Empty the Sharedpreferences from the ID value
                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("id_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                sp.edit().putString("id",  null).commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Res_Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }).show();


        break;

    }

    return true;

}
```

And this is the menu file (main.xml)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/home_page"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/Reseller_Menu"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/logout"/>

</menu>
```

And this is the strings.xml for the Arabic language. path:(res/values-ar/strings.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">مندوب المبيعات</string>
<string name="action_settings">الضبط</string>
<string name="hello_world">!مرحبا العالم</string>
<string name="Welcome_To_Reseller">مرحبا بك في مندوب المبيعات</string>
<string name="phone">الهاتف</string>
<string name="Password">كلمة المرور</string>
<string name="Login">تسجيل دخول</string>
<string name="Name">الإسم</string>
<string name="Register">إنشاء</string>
<string name="Confirm_Password">تأكيد كلمة المرور</string>
<string name="Register_Account">إنشاء حساب جديد</string>
<string name="Reseller_Menu">الصفحة الرئيسية</string>
<string name="Balance_Transfer">تحويل الرصيد</string>
<string name="Buy_Internet_Package">شراء باقة إنترنت</string>
<string name="Account_Details">تفاصيل الحساب</string>
<string name="Enter_Balance_Amount">أدخل المبلغ هنا</string>
<string name="send">إرسال</string>
<string name="Enter_Receiver_Phone">أدخل رقم الهاتف المستقبل هنا</string>
<string name="back">الصفحة السابقة</string>
<string name="Welcome">مرحبا</string>
<string name="my_details">تفاصيل حسابي</string>
<string name="internet_subscription">إشتراك الإنترنت:</string>
<string name="balance">الرصيد:</string>
<string name="view">عرض</string>
<string name="sdg">جنيه سوداني</string>
<string name="logo">logo</string>
<string name="enter_phone">أدخل رقم هاتفك هنا</string>
<string name="enter_password">أدخل كلمة مرورك هنا</string>
<string name="enter_name">أدخل إسمك هنا</string>
<string name="enter_confirm_password">أعد كتابة كلمة مرورك هنا</string>
<string name="amount">المبلغ</string>
<string name="balance_amount">كمية الرصيد</string>
<string name="logout">تسجيل خروج</string>
</resources>
```

And here is a screenshot of my Package Explorer to make sure of the files and folders paths.
[image]

And this is a screenshot of the Activity in English language, you can see the logo and the menu items:
[image]

And this is a screenshot of the Activity in Arabic Language, there is no menu or logo appearing:
[image]

Comment: you set `setTitle`, `setMessage` is hardcoded, use string resource

Comment: @Waki ....Please could you be more specific ??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a menu-ar resource folder and copy your main.xml to it.

Comment: this error:   Multiple markers at this line
  ar cannot be resolved to a 
  variable.........
  R.menu cannot be resolved to a 
  variable

Comment: You may need to clean and rebuild. Can you paste the stack trace of the error.

Comment: i don't think so. because i can't even run the app with that error.

Comment: What about the error from the build. Also what do your layouts look like between the ar folder and the main folder are they the same?

Comment: Basically there is no error, the error i told you about happens when i make a folder of (menu-ar) like you told me to do.

I added 2 more screenshots above in the main question, you can check them to see the both layouts, the English and the Arabic.

Comment: If you look clearly between the two layouts, you will see the English layout has a black menu bar, contains the logo and the Menu Items.  
I think the problem maybe in the (drawable) folders where it contains the logo, i think there must be (drawable-ar) or something like that, because the Arabic layout doesn't show the logo.

Comment: Yea my question is more what do the two layout files themselves contain that you're using for that screen not the resource folder. Are the layout files identical.

Comment: Yes they are, but not 100% , just a matter of spaces and size of some texts.

Answer (score 0):

Use string resources.

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.home_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.you_are_on_home_page)
    .setNeutralButton(R.string.btn_ok,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            //Do Nothing
        }
    }).show();
```

For two language (en/ar) add to `strings.xml` 
example,
en:

```
<string name="you_are_on_home_page">You Are In The Home Page Now</string>
```

ar:

```
<string name="you_are_on_home_page">مندوب المبيعات</string>
```

About right justify text in Dialog, you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131224

Comment: i did your steps, but nothing changed with the Menu Item problem.

Comment: @RamiRasikh do you added all your strings ? In my answer I shown just one string example.

Comment: yes i added all my strings to the (strings.xml) file in both languages.
and even if i wrote hardcoded strings in the Dialog, that dialog has nothing to do with the Menu Item problem in Arabic language, because it works in the English language.