# Changing background of AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

We can change properties of each `TextView` or `Button` that is in `AlertDialog`.For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063444/1043882) you can see the way to change properties of TextView,or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077918/1043882) for Button.**But my question is in about changing properties of root view of AlertDialog**.It may be done with `findViewById()`,but it needs ID of root view and I do not know it or it may be done in another way.Do you know how I can do it?

Note:My question **is not** in about creating `custom AlertDialog`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3119581/646806

Comment: Hi see this [Customizing Alert Dialog][1] In which he added a custom view to the alert Dialog

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the background of Android alert dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs)